# MIME Formatting issue

Tags: email, utf-8, mime-types

I have a question regarding MIME formatting and emails. Every now and again I get this kind of message come through. What could be causing it and what possible fix could I implement? The client is Outlook and the server is Exchange 2003.

Thanks

> From: Administrator Sent: 25 June 2010
>   08:00 To: End User Subject: Server
>   Performance Report
>
> This is a multi-part message in MIME
>   format.
>
> ------=_NextPart_000_0000_01CB143C.786417D0
>
> Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>
> ```
>   boundary="----=_NextPart_001_0001_01CB143C.786688D0"
> ```
>
> ------=_NextPart_001_0001_01CB143C.786688D0
>
> Content-Type: text/plain;
>
> ```
>   charset="utf-8"
> ```
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>
> U2VydmVyIFBlcmZvcm1hbmNlIFJlcG9ydCBmb3IgSDJPIExpbmVuIFNlcnZpY2VzDQpSZXBv
>
> cnQg
>
> Y3JlYXRlZCBvbiAyNS8wNi8yMDEwIGF0IDA4OjAwDQogCQ0KX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19f
>
> X19f
>
> X19fX19fX19fX18NCg0KCQ0KDQoNCg0KU3VtbWFyeSBmb3IgSDJPU0VSVkVSDQoNCiAJU2Vy
>
> dmVy
>
> IGhhcyBiZWVuIHJ1bm5pbmc6IDE1IGRheXMgYW5kIDE3IGhvdXJzIAkNCiAJU2VydmVyIFNw
>
> ZWNp
>
> ZmljYXRpb25zIAlEZXRhaWxzIAkNCiAJUGVyZm9ybWFuY2UgU3VtbWFyeSAJRGV0YWlscyAJ
>
> DQog
>
> etc etc etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Subject: Server Performance Report" -> try to see your server settings...

Comment: That's just the subject of the email which came through :) There's an issue with the formatting somewhere and it's only this one particular type of email - I think it's an SBS Server Report.